# What's the difference in the "styles-es2015.js" and "styles.css" in the Angular 16 build chunk files?

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-5, angular10, angular16

I am in the process of upgrading an Angular app from v10 to v16.
I have cleared all the depedencies and have a successful build ready to deploy but there are changes in the initial chunk files.

The build bundle before the upgrade created "styles-es2015.js" file for the styles and created a "styles.css" file now.

Is there is any webpack config that can changes it back and what was the purpose of the change?

I tried to change webpack configs to revert is back to the .js extension, I am expecting the same bundle files as they were in Angular 10.